# Sequelize - Update a date field automatically on an event

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-hooks

I've a login table which stores the user login details. Whenever a user changes the password, ***lastPasswordChange*** field should get updated with the date of the password change. Now I'm manually updateing the field with **Date()**.

Is there any better way to do this in Sequelize.
Node.js and Mysql DB

Comment: You could use a trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [beforeSave(instance, options)](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/hooks/) hook in your model, like:

```
...
YourModel.addHook('beforeSave', async (modelInstance) => {
    // if password change is detected
    if (instance.changed('password')) {
      instance.lastPasswordChange= new Date();
    }
});
```